# Problem with #Import <AppKit/AppKit.h> in Xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to use NSImage which appears need to be imported from `<AppKit/AppKit.h>`. I have included the AppKit framework, and I do see `AppKit.h` there. But I am still getting compilation error saying `<AppKit/AppKit.h>` not found.

What I might missed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppKit is not available on the iPhone, nor is NSIMage. You need to bring in UIKit and use UIImage.

Comment: How Did You Take Over This Problem...?
i Have Replaced The <AppKit/AppKit.h> with UIKit but still al lot of errors